# Select an entire range of ip's with a statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day.

I have a problem with a spammer, using my site for his filthy purposes. The spammers IP is similar to `111.111.11.11` - completely static except for the last two numbers. Can I somehow target the range `00` - `99` in one single SQL query?

This is how I know I can deal with it (no action in the example):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ip = 111.111.11.00
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ip = 111.111.11.01
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ip = 111.111.11.02
/* etc. */
```

Can I somehow wildcard the last two numbers like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ip = 111.111.11.??
```

or loop through a range like (preferrably directly in phpmyadmin)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ip = 111.111.11.00 -> 111.111.11.99
```

I've been looking through the MySQL reference manual, but I am not quite sure what I am looking for. Any help is much appreciated.

Kind regards, 
Jimmy

EDIT: The `like`-operator was what I was looking for. One Wordpress plugin glitch exploiter is gonna get what one deserves. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: maybe the `like` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ip BETWEEN '111.111.11.00' AND '111.111.11.99'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ip LIKE '111.111.11.__'
```

Comment: You may wish to check if this works properly for 3 digits in the last octet, too: the range is 0-254, not 0-99

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Help me; I don't see the flaw in the first one. All those two-digit numbers '00', '01', '02', ... are in the range, aren't they? If, unlike the question stated, they can be one digit or three, then neither query works (but `WHERE ip LIKE '111.111.11.%'` would).

Comment: @Jon Story: That's an advice for the OP, right? He explicitely wants to cover the range range '00' - '99'. At least this is what he has told us.

Comment: Yeah that was for the OP, you've answered the question as asked

Comment: `BETWEEN '111.111.11.00' AND '111.111.11.99'` would match `111.111.11.200`.

Comment: The final range have thus far only included numbers between 00-99. Thank you. @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea. Note that, as written, this solution cannot use an index...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE INET_ATON(ip) BETWEEN 1869548288 AND 1869548387;
```

Comment: where 1869548288 and 1869548387 are `INET_ATON('111.111.11.0')` and `INET_ATON('111.111.11.99')` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Thorten's `like` is the simplest way to handle your particular problem.  If you had a more generic range, then you can use `right()`:

```
WHERE RIGHT(ip, 13) BETWEEN '111.111.11.00' AND '111.111.11.99'
```

Comment: That works fine for 0-99 (so technically correct for the question) but an IP can use 0-254, and this won't work for >99

Comment: @JonStory There seems to be no need to as of right now. Not sure how it works, but the first 8 numbers stay the same, and only the two last varies.